# How to handle OpenSSL SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ / WANT_WRITE on non-blocking sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, openssl

The OpenSSL library allows to read from an underlying socket with SSL_read and write to it with SSL_write. These functions maybe return with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE depending on their ssl protocol needs (for example when renegotiating a connection).

I don't really understand what the API wants me to do with these results.

Imaging a server app that accepts client connections, sets up a new ssl session, makes the underlying socket non-blocking and then adds the filedescriptor to a select/poll/epoll loop.

If a client sends data, the main loop will dispatch this to a ssl_read. What has to be done here if SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE is returned? WANT_READ might be easy, because the next main loop iteration could just lead to another ssl_read. But if the ssl_read return WANT_WRITE, with what parameters should it be called? And why doesn't the library issue the call itself?

If the server wants to send a client some data, it will use ssl_write. Again, what is to be done if WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE are returned? Can the WANT_WRITE be answered by repeating the very same call that just was invoked? And if WANT_READ is returned, should one return to the main loop and let the select/poll/epoll take care of this? But what about the message that should be written in the first place?

Or should the read be done right after the failed write? Then, what protects against reading bytes from the application protocol and then having to deal with it somewhere in the outskirts of the app, when the real parser sits in the mainloop?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

With non-blocking sockets, `SSL_WANT_READ` means *"wait for the socket to be readable, then call this function again."*; conversely, `SSL_WANT_WRITE` means *"wait for the socket to be writeable, then call this function again."*.  You can get either `SSL_WANT_WRITE` or `SSL_WANT_READ` from both an `SSL_read()` or `SSL_write()` call.

Comment: The best explanation here

Answer (score 20):

Did you read the OpenSSL documentation for [`SSL_read()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_read.html) and [`SSL_get_error()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_error.html) yet?

`SSL_read()`:

> If the underlying BIO is blocking,
> SSL_read() will only return, once the
> read operation has been finished or an
> error occurred, except when a
> renegotiation take place, in which
> case a SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ may occur.
> This behaviour can be controlled with
> the SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY flag of the
> SSL_CTX_set_mode(3) call.
>
> If the underlying BIO is non-blocking,
> SSL_read() will also return when the
> underlying BIO could not satisfy the
> needs of SSL_read() to continue the
> operation. In this case a call to
> SSL_get_error(3) with the return value
> of SSL_read() will yield
> SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or
> SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE. As at any time a
> re-negotiation is possible, a call to
> SSL_read() can also cause write
> operations! The calling process then
> must repeat the call after taking
> appropriate action to satisfy the
> needs of SSL_read(). The action
> depends on the underlying BIO. When
> using a non-blocking socket, nothing
> is to be done, but select() can be
> used to check for the required
> condition.

`SSL_get_error()`:

> SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE
>
> The operation did not complete; the
> same TLS/SSL I/O function should be
> called again later. If, by then, the
> underlying BIO has data available for
> reading (if the result code is
> SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) or allows writing
> data (SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE), then some
> TLS/SSL protocol progress will take
> place, i.e. at least part of an TLS/SSL
> record will be read or written. Note
> that the retry may again lead to a
> SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE
> condition. There is no fixed upper limit
> for the number of iterations that may
> be necessary until progress becomes
> visible at application protocol level.
>
> For socket BIOs (e.g. when SSL_set_fd()
> was used), select() or poll() on the
> underlying socket can be used to find
> out when the TLS/SSL I/O function
> should be retried.
>
> Caveat: Any TLS/SSL I/O function can
> lead to either of SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ
> and SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE. In particular,
> SSL_read() or SSL_peek() may want to
> write data and SSL_write() may want to
> read data. This is mainly because
> TLS/SSL handshakes may occur at any
> time during the protocol (initiated by
> either the client or the server);
> SSL_read(), SSL_peek(), and SSL_write()
> will handle any pending handshakes.

OpenSSL is implemented as a state machine. `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` means that more inbound data, and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` means that more outbound data, is needed in order to make forward progress on the connection.

If you get `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, OpenSSL needs to send outbound data but can't because the socket is no longer writable (the peer's receive buffer can't hold any more data), so you need to wait for the socket to become writable (the peer has freed up buffer space) and then retry the operation again.

If you get `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, OpenSSL needs to read inbound data but can't because the socket is no longer readable (the socket's receive buffer is empty), so you need to wait for the socket to become readable (more data has arrived) and then retry the operation again.

You should subscribe to the [OpenSSL mailing lists](http://www.openssl.org/support/community.html).  This question gets asked alot.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the docs. That's what brought me here :-) What I now begin to understand is that SSL_WANT_READ does *not* ask me to issue a SSL_read() nor does SSL_WANT_WRITE ask me to call SSL_write(), but just indicates that I should retry the very same call that just returned when the socket below become either readable or writeable. So, one should interpret them as SSL_WANTS_A_READABLE_SOCKET and SSL_WANTS_A_WRITEABLE_SOCKET.

Comment: Yes. I think the answer is wrong in saying that SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE means that more outbound data is needed. It means wait until the underlying socket becomes writeable.

Comment: I agree with what you say. But what I would like to see is a model read handler which calls SSL_read() and then shows what to do when it returns  0 or less. It is the fact that does not exist which is why the question is asked a lot.

Answer (score 9):

SSL_WANT_READ means that the SSL engine can't currently encrypt for you as it's waiting for more input data (either as part of the initial handshake or as part of a renegotiation), so, once your next read has completed and you've pushed the data that arrived through the SSL engine you can retry your write operation.

Likewise, SSL_WANT_WRITE means that the SSL engine is waiting for you to extract some data from it and send it to the peer.

I wrote about using OpenSSL with non blocking and async sockets back in 2002 for Windows Developer Journal (reprinted [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/using-openssl-with-asynchronous-sockets.html)) and although this article is ostensibly aimed at Windows code the principals are the same for other platforms. The article comes with some code that integrates OpenSSL with async sockets on Windows and which deals with the whole SSL_WANT_READ/SSL_WANT_WRITE issue.

Essentially, when you get an SSL_WANT_READ you need to queue outbound data until you've had a read complete and you've passed the new inbound data into the SSL engine, once that has happened you can retry sending your outbound data.

Comment: Ok, SSL_WANT_READ returned from SSL_write() is understood, I just queue up all outgoing messages somewhere in the app until the a SSL_read() succeeds, then I try again. So if I run out of memory while buffering, I have to either drop app messages or drop that connection.

Now, if the SSL_read() returns SSL_WANT_WRITE and I don't have any data this means that I have to do a zero length SSL_write() to satisfy that request, before sucessfully reading again?

Comment: With SSL_WANT_WRITE you may find that you have data that needs extracting from the BIO and sending to the other side. You shouldn't have to push a zero byte write through the BIO to generate this as far as I can remember.