SSL_connect on epoll f-stack socket in C++
I'm building an (EPOLL client) application in C++ that connects to a server via f-stack (and dpdk). My f-stack and dpdk is set up correctly and my code works if I connect a socket to google.com on port 80 and send a GET request. I mainly used this repo for accomplishing this: https://github.com/Luo-Liang/F-stack-bw2/blob/master/main_client.cpp
But, I need a TLS connection, so I'm trying to turn the (ff_)socket into a TLS socket. Here is (part of) the code:
int loop(void *arg)
{
    int nevents = PLinkEpollWait(epfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, 0);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nevents; ++i)
    {
        // std::cout << "event? " << events[i].events << std::endl;
        if (events[i].events & EPOLLERR)
        {
            /* Simply close socket */
            PLinkEpollCtrl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, NULL);
            PLinkClose(events[i].data.fd);
            printf("EPOLLERR. %s=?\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN)
        {
            ssize_t readlen = PLinkRead(events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (readlen > 0)
            {
                bytesRecv += readlen;
                PLinkWrite(events[i].data.fd, req, sizeof(req));
            }
            else
            {
                PLinkEpollCtrl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, NULL);
                PLinkClose(events[i].data.fd);
            }
        }
        if (events[i].events & EPOLLOUT)
        {
            std::cout << "ready to send " << std::endl;

            SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
            if (!ssl)
            {
                std::cerr << "SSL_new failed on fd: " << events[i].data.fd << std::endl;
                PLinkEpollCtrl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, NULL);
                PLinkClose(events[i].data.fd);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            SSL_set_fd(ssl, events[i].data.fd);
            SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);

            SSL_set_info_callback(ssl, [](const SSL *ssl, int where, int ret)
                {
                    std::cout << where << " callback " << ret << std::endl;
                    if (ret == 0) {
                        printf("SSL error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr));
                        return;
                    }
                    const char *str = (where & SSL_ST_CONNECT) ? "SSL_connect" : "undefined";
                    int w = where & ~SSL_ST_MASK;
                    if (w & SSL_CB_LOOP) {
                        printf("%s: %s\n", str, SSL_state_string_long(ssl));
                    } else if (w & SSL_CB_ALERT) {
                        const char *alertType = (where & SSL_CB_READ) ? "read" : "write";
                        printf("SSL Alert [%s]: %s: %s\n", alertType,
                            SSL_alert_type_string_long(ret), SSL_alert_desc_string_long(ret));
                    } else if (w & SSL_CB_EXIT) {
                        if (ret == 0) {
                            printf("%s: failed in %s\n", str, SSL_state_string_long(ssl));
                        } else if (ret < 0) {
                            printf("%s: error in %s\n", str, SSL_state_string_long(ssl));
                        }
                    } });

            for (;;)
            {
                int success = SSL_connect(ssl);
                if (success < 0)
                {
                    int ssl_error_code = SSL_get_error(ssl, success);
                    if (ssl_error_code == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ || ssl_error_code == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
                    {
                        printf("SSL_connect waiting for more data, error code: %d\n", ssl_error_code);

                        // Wait for epoll to notify the appropriate event
                        int nevents = PLinkEpollWait(epfd, events, 1, 5000); // 1000ms timeout
                        if (nevents < 0)
                        {
                            perror("PLinkEpollWait failed");
                            SSL_free(ssl);
                            PLinkClose(events[i].data.fd);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }

                        // Continue to let the loop retry SSL_connect based on the appropriate event
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (ssl_error_code == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)
                    {
                        printf("SSL_connect: close notify received from peer\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Error SSL_connect: %d\n", ssl_error_code);
                        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                        SSL_free(ssl);
                        PLinkClose(events[i].data.fd);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dump_cert_info(ssl, false);
                    printf("SSL handshake completed successfully.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string serverIp = "172.217.174.110";
    int port = 443;

    initializeSSL();

    PLinkInit(argc, argv);
    printf("f-stack initialized.\n");

    epfd = PLinkEpollCreate();
    if (epfd < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "PLinkEpollCreate failed, errno: " << errno << " (" << strerror(errno) << ")" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Epoll instance created with fd: %d\n", epfd);

    int sockfd = PLinkSocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "PLinkSocket failed, errno: " << errno << " (" << strerror(errno) << ")" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Socket created with fd: %d\n", sockfd);

    PLinkSetNonBlock(sockfd);
    auto CLIENT_PORT = (uint16_t)(1024 + rand() % (49000));
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(CLIENT_PORT);
    // bind to any of my address.
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    std::string sip = serverIp;

    int ret = PLinkBind(sockfd, (const sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        printf("PLinkBind failed, errno = %s\n", strerror(errno));
        for (auto sock : sockfdVec)
        {
            PLinkClose(sock);
        }
        exit(1);
    }
    struct epoll_event ev;
    ev.data.fd = sockfd;
    ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT;
    PLinkEpollCtrl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd, &ev);
    sockaddr_in remote_addr;
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, sip.c_str(), &(remote_addr.sin_addr));
    ret = PLinkConnect(sockfd, (const sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    if (ret < 0 && errno != EINPROGRESS)
    {
        // ff_connect can return EINPROGRESS as it is always nb
        printf("ff_connect failed %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    // ssl_map[sockfd] = ssl;
    PLinkRun(loop, NULL);

    SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx);
    return 0;
}

What I'm getting is during SSL_connect the program just hangs, it doesn't get past SSL_connect. I get this output:
f-stack initialized.
Epoll instance created with fd: 0
Socket created with fd: 1
ready to send 
16 callback 1
4097 callback 1
 a;��.D��HT�`��^����ՠ��U�bѫ ʔ��"qۃ���.�������\�ӌ҉c��>�,�0�̨̩̪�+�/��$�(k�#�'g�
�9�     �3��=<5/��

*(

+-3&$ O��+�7�Y�=���m�����{��Vѕt1�h4097 callback 1

The where variable in the callback is 4097, which maybe is a combination of SSL_ST_CONNECT (0x1000) and SSL_CB_LOOP (0x001) flags.
I'm on RHEL 7.5, OpenSSL 3.1.3, g++ (GCC) 7.3.1.
Is there someone who can help me out?

Using non-blocking sockets with OpenSSL requires a little backwards thinking. You need to perform the socket operation first and then use select()/epoll() to finish the operation only when OpenSSL explicitly tells you to (ie, when it gives you a WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE error). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952104/ Polling the socket before OpenSSL has something worth polling for will usually not end well. I don't see you adjusting your epoll_event based on OpenSSL's current state - ie, don't ask for EPOLLIN when OpenSSL isn't ready for you to read, etc.
